# How to speed up scipy interpolate?

Tags: python, performance, scipy, interpolation

I'm using scipy interpolate to find the a smooth approximation of different columns of a quasi-large data frame (of length around 240,000) then find the slope at interval midpoints like so:

```
tck = sc.interpolate.splrep(data['Time'], np.array(data[columname]), s=3)    
slope =sc.interpolate.splev(interval_midpoints_array, tck, der=1)
```

For some columns this works well and very fast, but for others it takes what seems to me a long time (at least 15-20 minutes before I gave up).

I read [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3531) that the univariate spline has speed problems with NaN values, however I checked and there are no NaN values in my data frame. I also tried increasing the s value, but it had no significant effect on the time.

Is there a way to speed up the interpolation? Or a better way to approximate these slope values that is faster? Am I just impatient?

Is there a way to characterize data sets on which different approaches are faster?

Edit: added some sample data below

```
AT.data['Fast'][0:25]
0     0.9531
1     0.9536
2     0.9557
3     0.9578
4     0.9599
5     0.9625
6     0.9538
7     0.9143
8     0.9429
9     0.9773
10    0.9802
11    0.9831
12    0.9846
13    0.9849
14    0.9849
15    0.9826
16    0.9811
17    0.9791
18    0.9780
19    0.9773
20    0.9758
21    0.9752
22    0.9743
23    0.9737
24    0.9742
Name: Fast, dtype: float64

AT.data['Slow'][0:25]
0     105.1
1     105.1
2     105.1
3     105.1
4     105.1
5     105.1
6     105.1
7     105.0
8     105.0
9     105.0
10    105.0
11    105.0
12    105.0
13    105.0
14    104.9
15    104.9
16    104.9
17    104.8
18    104.8
19    104.8
20    104.8
21    104.7
22    104.7
23    104.7
24    104.7
Name: Slow, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Can you show some example data points for a slow and a fast column? I suspect some of them might be of data types that don't play nicely with scipy.